# Expression of type 'Boolean' expected with dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, linq, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I used Kendo Grid in ASP.NET MVC and I created a custom server side filter like this:

```
public string CreateString(IEnumerable<IFilterDescriptor> filters, string defaultFilter)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (filters == null || filters.Count() == 0)
    {
        _filterstring = defaultFilter;
        return _filterstring;
    }
    if (filters.Any())
    {
        foreach (Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor filter in filters)
        {
            string template = Templates[filter.Operator.ToString().ToLower()];
            builder.AppendFormat(template, filter.Member, filter.Value);
        }
    }
    _filterstring = builder.ToString();

    return _filterstring;
}

private static readonly IDictionary<string, string> Templates = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "eq", "{0} = '{1}'" },
    { "neq", "{0} <> '{1}'" },
    { "lt", "{0} < '{1}'" },
    { "lte", "{0} <= '{1}'" },
    { "gt", "{0} > '{1}'" },
    { "gte", "{0} >= '{1}'" },
    { "startswith", "{0} like '{1}*'" },
    { "endswith", "{0} like '*{1}'" },
    { "contains", "{0} like '*{1}*'" },
    { "doesnotcontain", "{0} not like '*{1}*'" }
};
```

That returns a `string` like this:

```
Title like '*a*'
```

And I used `Linq.Dynamic` and I filter the data sets like:

```
var articleCategories = _articleCategories.AsQueryable();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
        articleCategories = articleCategories.Where(filter).ToList();
```

But it returns this error:

> Expression of type 'Boolean' expected.

Comment: Does this also happen when you have only one filter string? Multiple filters you should be separated by `&&` .

Comment: oh , I forgot add `&&` . always happen only or multiple . how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really good with those, but you might be lacking a logical `and` between you filters? I added one in your code, but I am not really good with this. Tell me if it works.

```
if (filters == null || filters.Count() == 0)
{
    _filterstring = defaultFilter;
    return _filterstring;
}
if (filters.Any())
{
    string template = Templates[filters[0].Operator.ToString().ToLower()];
    builder.AppendFormat(template, filter.Member, filter.Value);
    if (filters.Count() > 1) {
        foreach (Kendo.Mvc.FilterDescriptor filter in filters.Skip(1))
        {
            template = " && " + Templates[filter.Operator.ToString().ToLower()];
            builder.AppendFormat(template, filter.Member, filter.Value);
        }
    }
}
```